# change the font family of the react native picker not working even with android style of picker

Tags: android, react-native, picker

change the font family of the react native picker not working even with android style of picker
here is my code from android styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<!-- Dropdown options font. -->
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>

</style>
 <!-- Dropdown options font. -->
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>

</style>
```

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518717/change-the-font-family-of-the-react-native-picker-not-working-even-with-android

Comment: it is not working